Is there a way to change the X axis on ridgeplots in Seurat?
I am trying to make multiple ridgeplots in Seurat and I would like to compare them so I want them to have the same X axis, but I cannot figure out how to choose the min and max values, it is automatically done. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!
I cannot find any functions to change the x axis
